# Drawing more current from a battery than what it was designed for

Tags: protection, discharge, batteries, bms

I have built a system that requires at least 8A to run properly. It is powered by 6S1P li-ion battery pack protected by BMS circuit. I did some research and found that maximum battery current output drops as it gets more and more discharged. So my battery pack could potentially drop below that threshold of 8A after being dramatically discharged. I know that the BMS circuit is supposed to avoid this situation by cutting off the power when the pack drops under certain voltage, but what would happen if this feature fails. I am having some doubts about the quality of my BMS, so I could someone please explain to me, what would happen if the pack is no longer capable of delivering the required current and the BMS would fail or wouldn't be there at all. Would it short itself or just shut down?

Comment: As you drain the battery the voltage decreases, which will limit your current and brown out your device.  You should be handling the case of power supply brown out regardless of how good your BMS is if you're running on battery.

Comment: It depends what the load is. If it is a resistive load, it will draw less current when it receives less voltage. If it is a switch mode power supply that draws constant power, it will draw more current when voltage drops.

Comment: Don't have doubts about the quality of your BMS!  Would you use cheap Chinese for your house's circuit breakers?  Safety gear should be quality.